# JQuery Table Row click not working (only in IE)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, events

The script works perfect both in Firefox and Opera.

```
         $(document).ready(function()
         { 
            $('#mainTable tr').each(function() 
            { 
                $(this).on("click",( function () 
                {
                        alert("Test");
                }));
            });
          });
```

No alert in IE (Version 9).

I have looked around, and it seems like a common problem, but I couldn't find any solution.

EDIT:
Here is a test link for fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BH6Us/

Thanks.

Comment: It could have been alot simpler with : `$('#mainTable tr').click(function(){...})`

Comment: Anyway, can you please set a fiddle?

Comment: @gdoron I'm afraid I don't know what it is. when I tested the HTML here: http://jsfiddle.net/, it dosen't alert as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need `each`, that doesn't work because the handler is within the each function, which is called only once, in fact each should be called first for triggering `click` function.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('#mainTable tr').click(function() {
      alert("Test");
   });
});
```

Comment: It doesnt answer the question. It should have been a comment about best practice.

Comment: @gdoron should i migrate ma answer to comment section?

Comment: Actually I wrote that as a comment one minute before your answer... :)

Comment: Thanks Raminson and gdoron, while it dosen't fix the problem, it makes much smaller code.

Comment: @Raminson it is getting strange, now it works in fiddle.  but not from a local file. It seems like you've changed something, what it is?

Comment: @Esh i just added `$(this).text()` which returns selected `tr` object text.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably better get off by using on() like this instead.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$("#mainTable tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
        alert('Test');
    });
```